# Find top k visiting URL for last day, or last hour, or last minute?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hash, binary-heap, streaming-algorithm

The original question is given file containing 5GB URL being visited last day, find the top k frequent URL. The problem can be solved by using hash map to count the occurrences of distinct URL and find top k with the help of min heap, taking a O(n log k) time.

Now I'm thinking what if the input was unlimited online data stream (instead of static file), then how can I know the top k URL of the last day?

Or is there any improvement that I can made to the system that allow me to get top k URL for last minute and last day and last hours dynamically?

Any hint will be appreciated!!

Comment: checkout http://stackoverflow.com/a/10190836/404145

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to settle for a probabilistic answer that might contain a few wrong entries, you should definitely look into the **[count-min sketch](https://sites.google.com/site/countminsketch/)** data structure.  It was specifically designed to estimate frequent elements in a stream using as little memory as possible, and most implementations support a very time and space efficient approximation of the top k elements out of a stream.  Moreover, the structure lets you tune space usage, which makes it ideal for situations like these.  IIRC Google uses this to determine their most frequent search queries.

There are [several implementations of this data structure](https://sites.google.com/site/countminsketch/code) available online.

Hope this helps!